# count($_SESSION) always returns 0

Tags: php, session

I wrote this script:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/stile.css"> 
</head>
<body>

<?php
include_once("../../classi/funzioni.php");
include_once("../../classi/config.php");
include_once("../../classi/auth.lib.php");

session_start(); //Inizio la sessione

list($status, $user) = auth_get_status();

if($status == AUTH_LOGGED && $user['nome_negozio']=="Black Fashion"){

echo "<h1>ORDINE DA CLIENTE</h1>";

$prodotto="SELECT * FROM elenco_movimenti WHERE cliente='".$user['nome_negozio']."'";//query
echo "<br><b>QUERY</b><br>";    
echo $prodotto; 

$prodotto=$db_magazzino->query($prodotto);
$prodotto=$prodotto->fetch_row(); 

$i=count($_SESSION);    
$_SESSION[$i]=$prodotto; 
}

?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="./ordine_da_cliente.php">
<label for="barcode"><b>Codice a barre</b></label>
<input type="text" name="barcode" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

NB

`$i=count($_SESSION); 
$_SESSION[$i]=$prodotto;`

Then if the session has 0 elements, i set $_SESSION[0] width the product, and i see it with var_dump:

`VAR DUMP SESSION 
array(1) { [0]=> array(14) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(19) "2014-10-12 08:31:18" [2]=> string(18) "Carico da articoli" [3]=> string(13) "0913VLA002001" ETC...`

but the next count is always zero and i see the same vardump...

Why don't i see $_SESSION[0][0][1][2]. $_SESSION[1][0][1][2], etcetera?

Comment: First time, the count is 0 if you do not set anything to the `$_SESSION` variable. After that, it should be 1, after that 2, etc... After the `session_start()` insert a `var_dump($_SESSION)` to check, is you `$_SESSION` filled.

Comment: yes, it is always filled with only one element, and counts always 0.

Comment: you wrote: "I wrote this function:" you mean script. and do you start the session on that page, where the form is? And where is the `$user['nome_negozio']` came from? Can you edit your post, and show me the whole script if it is not too large?

Comment: Why not use associative arrays.. that looks confusing

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/stile.css"> 
</head>
<body>

<?php
include_once("../../classi/funzioni.php");
include_once("../../classi/config.php");
include_once("../../classi/auth.lib.php");

session_start(); //Inizio la sessione
```

By sending everything between `<html>` and `<?php`, you [have already sent headers to the browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#89989) and thus the browser will not have a session variable stored between pages. So PHP will have an empty `$_SESSION` every time for each user between each page load since the browser hasn't stored the session ID from your server, but will still store `$_SESSION` variables within the immediate script execution as if you were using just any other variable.

Change your code to use `session_start` before **any** browser output.

```
<?php
session_start(); //Inizio la sessione

include_once("../../classi/funzioni.php");
include_once("../../classi/config.php");
include_once("../../classi/auth.lib.php");

?><html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/stile.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // .. Rest of your code
```

And just so you know, [if you read the docs fully,](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#refsect1-function.session-start-notes) it states:

> **Note:**
>   To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: no, it still doesn't work :( any other ways?

PS If i do var_dump($_SESSION) from another page in the server (in the same folder) it displays 0 elements (also if i set $_SESSION[0]="lorem ipsium";... Why??? The other pages (that have the $_SESSION vars) of the site work properly.

Comment: @RiparazioneComputerMestreDa Are you truly using `session_start()` before sending any output? Even a single space before the `<?php` can break the starting of a session.

Comment: yes, i confirm. no one space from <?php to session_start();

Comment: @RiparazioneComputerMestreDa No, not from `<?php` to `session_start()`. There has to be **no HTML** and **no spaces** before the beginning of the very document to the beginning of `<?php session_start()`

Comment: <?php
session_start(); //Inizio la sessione
include_once("../../classi/funzioni.php");
include_once("../../classi/config.php");
include_once("../../classi/auth.lib.php");


list($status, $user) = auth_get_status();
?>
<html>

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:

If i delete the following lines:

```
include_once("../../classi/funzioni.php");    
include_once("../../classi/config.php");    
include_once("../../classi/auth.lib.php");
```

The page config.php contained this line:
    `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); //0 E_ALL`

Then i see this notice:
`Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 1 in Unknown on line 0`

Then if i write this:
    `$_SESSION['ordine_'.'1']="Ciao come stai?";`

It saves the sessions. I don't like this method very much, but now it works.

Thank you anyway for the support.

Kind regards.